# Cannot find mapping for Status field

Tags: acumatica

My application is integrated with Acumatica 2020R2. When I try to create a task (`PUT /ProjectTask`) with such body:

```json
{
  "Description": {
    "value": "xxx"
  },
  "ProjectID": {
    "value": "xxx"
  },
  "TaskID": {
    "value": "xxx"
  },
  "Type2020R1": {
    "value": "CostRev"
  }
}
```

I get an error: `Cannot find mapping for Status field: status.`. The same when I add "Status" value to the payload. Any idea what this message means and when it can occur?

Comment: Do you have any customizations on that page? Are you using a custom Endpoint or the default one? What is this `Type2020R1` field?

Comment: It's our internal field, it doesn't matter. I found that client is using 2021R1, so there is a mismatch of versions. Our integration doesn't support it. I guess this is the reason of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment above: client is using different Acumatica version (2021R1), our integration doesn't support it.